# TFS 2015 Update 2 TF246018 error creating agent

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

Have been attempting to remedy this. The only solution I found in googling involves changing the settings for the VM NIC card, however, we use Hyper V and those configuration settings are not available. Currently a TFS 2013 build server resides and operates properly on this machine. TFS operates on another VM, but there appears to be no connection issues for the 2013  versions TFS=>TFSBuild=>TFSDB

Thanks.

Complete Error Message:

C:\Users\svc_tfsbuild\Agent>ConfigureAgent.cmd

```
Enter the name for this agent (default is Agent-WPTFS05) VS2015U2
Enter the URL for the Team Foundation Server (default is ) http://tfs:8080/tfs
Configure this agent against which agent pool? (default pool name is 'default') VS2015U2
Enter the path of the work folder for this agent (default is 'C:\Users\svc_tfsbuild\Agent\_work')
Would you like to install the agent as a Windows Service (Y/N) (default is N) Y
Enter the name of the user account to use for the service (default is NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE) svc_tfsService
Enter the password for user account svc_tfsService:
TF246018: The database operation exceeded the timeout limit and has been cancelled. Verify that the parameters of the operation are correct.
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to deploy a windows agent for TFS 2015.2 on the Build 2013 build machine? Are you able to deploy the windows agent on your TFS 2015.2 machine?

Comment: @Cece Thanks for your reply. We have a dedicated TFS server and a dedicated TFS Build server. Both servers have been upgraded to TFS 2015 Upgrade 2 from TFS 2013. From the web portal, we are currently able to run all of our existing XAML builds (which we will continue to need to do). Currently, we were able to create a TFS 2015 pool from the web portal, but are unable to create a build agent without the error listed above. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you already created a pool named "VS2015U2" on web portal?

Comment: @Cece Yes, without issue.

Comment: How about deploying the windows agent on your TFS 2015.2 machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The bug was fixed in TFS 2015 Update 3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2016/06/07/team-foundation-server-2015-update-3-rc-is-available/) This issue was actually caused by a bug which would not allow creation of a build agent with an underscore character in the service name.